# How to prevent Maven from accessing remote repositories?

Tags: maven-2, build

How can I enforce Maven to **only use my local repository and single specific repository on intranet** and not downloading anything from internet? Even my POMs all has single company's internal repository specified, maven goes to internet repositories taken from libs' POM files to fetch dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your settings.xml (usually under %user.home%/.m2) you can configure this.

E.g.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>repo.example.com</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Internal repo</name>
      <url>http://repo.example.com/repo</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

The key part there is the `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` which means that all requests will be directed at this repository.

Comment: I've tried and it did worked out. I will wait a bit before marking this as solution, since it looks like hack - I was hoping for some specific option or cmd line param etc. Thanks for solving my practical issue anyways!

Comment: This isn't a hack at all, this is how you configure a global repository manager.   It is what we recommend people to do when they've setup something like Nexus.