# In Maven, how can I switch between local and intranet repositories on a per-project basis?

Tags: maven

I've been using Maven for projects, and these projects regularly connect to external, intra-net based repositories. I want to do a few one-off's at times, and I don't want them to connect to my intranet--just strictly my local repository.

In my `settings.xml` file, I've added a second profile for these projects, so that I can specify that profile during during builds, but I don't know how to tell it I only want to search a local repository at `/path/to/my/local/repo`.

Is a secondary profile the right approach here, or should I do something with running Maven in offline (`-o`) mode and adding a new mirror? [I've seen some approaches similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164975/how-to-prevent-maven-from-accessing-remote-repositories), but not sure how to set a path instead of a url in the mirror declaration.

Comment: I didn't catch, what's the problem with `-o` command line option? It's the most simple and most straightforward way to force maven to use your local repository only.

Comment: I assumed with `-o` it would need some sort of mirror/path setup? If not, then it does sound like the best solution.

Comment: With `-o` it's simple. If you don't have something that your build requires in your local repository, build fails. That's it.

Comment: I see now--it's failing, but looking in local and not intranet, which is great. I'm assuming something like `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.something -DartifactId=theArtifact -Dversion=1.2.3` ... will get me there? PS If you want to put your comments in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to achieve going offline. Can you be more specific? P.S. I don't think my comment is worth an answer since you have an answer in your question =)

Comment: I'm trying to install a [Cassandra client for Scala](https://github.com/twitter/cassie), but want it to be only in my local/offline repo. When I try to build my project, I am getting `The repository system is offline but the artifact com.twitter:cassie:jar:0.19.2 is not available in the local repository.`

Comment: In this case the above mentioned (`install-file`) should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @andrew_logvinov for pointing out that it's relatively easy to do this by just specifying a "`-o`" to your `mvn` request. You don't need any local mirror setups or profiles in your settings.xml file.

If you need to install a file into your local repository, you'd do:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.something -DartifactId=theArtifact -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dfile=/local/path/to/the/file/some.pom -Dpackaging=pom
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep around two copies of maven. In one, conf/settings.xml has <mirrors/> for our corporate Nexus server. In the other, it does not. You can extend this technique as needed, maven install trees are not very large.

Comment: How do you specify which maven you want to use on a project?

Comment: I type a different command. I have aliases in my shell startup that specify. If you mean different subprojects of a parent, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to separate this is to have a separate settings.xml for the different use cases of repo/no repo, company 1 user, company 2 user, private hacking on github and so on.

Then you can either switcht the settings files around or use the command line flag for specifying the settings file -s.